# How can I use SQL queries in Excel to join two tables on different worksheets in the same workbook?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have two tables each in different worksheets in a single workbook. I have a SQL statement that joins, transforms, and derives complex fields (that cannot be addressed with a Power Query join) from the two tables and I want to tell Excel to execute that SQL statement on the tables.

My issue is, I don't know how to make this happen on two tables that are already in the workbook. It's fine if the two tables lived on a DB because Excel gives me a native query dialog box as I connect to the database, but the same is not true for data sourced from tables in the Workbook.

Basically I want Excel to execute this SQL statement:

```sql
create table joined_table as 
select id, property_1 from [Sheet1$A1B100] as a
left join id, property_2 from [Sheet2$A1B50] as b
on a.id=b.id
```

I have no idea where I can instruct Excel to do this, nor if the query can be executed as a native SQL query. Truly appreciate any advice.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using a spreadsheet, but a database.

Comment: You can use power query. Merge as new and left outer join table two to table one with property column. Will keep all rows from one and join table two on that

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO to connect to an Excel file and use a worksheet as a database table. But it's difficult in 64bit office and assumes you have the ADO drivers for excel installed. The data has to stored in an XLSX format file, with one table per sheet, and by default it assumes that the field names are on the first row with the data below. 
(I don't have the drivers and I'm in 64 bit office so I can't give you an example but 
[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w) might help

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, however not straightforward.

Let's say your tables are in separate sheets 'table1' and 'table2'. First step is from [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-sql-statements-ms-excel-41193.html)

- Click “Data” on the Excel Ribbon. Click the “From Other Sources” icon in the Get External Data section. Click “From Microsoft Query” on the drop-down menu
- Select excel file (current excel file)
- If you do not see tables please see [this link](https://www.excelhowto.com/microsoft-query-error-this-data-source-contains-no-visible-tables/)
- Add tables to list, you will probably see an error that Microsoft Query could not automatically join tables. Click ok.
- Add query (view->SQL)

Query (please note the backticks):

```
SELECT table1$.id, table1$.property_1, table2$.property_2 
FROM {oj `C:\yourpath\yourfile.xlsx`.`table1$` `table1$`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `C:\yourpath\yourfile.xlsx`.`table2$` `table2$`
ON  table2$.id =table1$.id}
```

- File -> Return data to excel